# Adding the values in a foreach before displaying the final result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a shopping cart which passes a ship value of each item.

When I want to display the total shipping cost I tried the code below.

```
foreach ($cart as $item)
echo $ship = $this->cart->format_number($item['ship']);
```

Assume I have three items in my cart.

- Item 1 = $30 shipping
- Item 2 = $20 shipping
- Item 3 = $30 shipping

I need to `add` these values before echoing out the `result` However my code outputs `30.0020.0030.00`

## question:

How do I `add` the values before echoing out the result?

--useful info-- using codeigniter shopping cart

Comment: How are you trying to add them?

Comment: By `add` you mean `sum`?

Comment: yes - i tried `array_split` and `sum` but getting errors. I think my syntax is off.

Comment: FYI, to add numbers together you'd generally use the addition operator `+`. Seems obvious to me but I didn't see anything that suggests you were aware of it.

Comment: At @WesleyMurch How would I use the `+` operator? I don't know if the cart will have 1 item or 25 items. I wouldn't make sense to count items and `+` each one...

Comment: I suppose the non-obvious part is that you create a variable with the total, then add to it in each iteration of the loop, as Damien's answer exhibits. Alternative syntax (maybe easier to understand) would be `$total = ($total + $ship);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add progressively at each iteration, you're just echoing out now...

```
$total = 0;

foreach ($cart as $item)
{
  $total += $this->cart->format_number($item['ship']);
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: IMHO, this shouldn't be answered...

Comment: yep perfect solution. thank you. I will check your answer post time limit. Thanks again :)

Comment: @AlixAxel IMHO your opinion isn't humble at all. Remember back when you were learning. As simple as something may seem to you can be quite difficult to someone learning.

Comment: @fabio: Something this rudimentary (addition) shouldn't require anything but the most basic research. I think it would be more helpful for your sake as a programmer to direct you to the proper resourse rather than spoon-feed you. Here you go: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: @fabio: IMHO, someone learning might as well learn by RTFM not by asking trivial questions one should have learnt in the primary school. You're coding a shopping cart for crying out loud, what other kind of perplexities might be in there I wonder.

Comment: @AlixAxel I'm coding a shopping cart as learning experience not for a production environment. You're seriously full of judgement 'for crying out loud'.

Comment: @fabio: Fair enough. But for someone who claims having expert web development skills in PHP, Ruby, Python and .NET and then says "wouldn't make sense to count items and + each one" I strongly suggest you RTFM, here are some links to start: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html (notice the `$this->cart->total()`?), http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.